# jQuery can't find div with specified id

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html

I am using jQuery to find a div with a specific id, except it return null. This is strange since trying to find other divs works just fine.

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Finds parent div without a problem
    console.log($('#next-sheet'));

    //Returns null, can't find the div I really need
    console.log($('#start-course'));

    //Also returns null
    console.log($('#next-button'));

    //Still returns null, can't find the div
    console.log($('#next-sheet #start-course'));
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='next-sheet'>
    <a href="/courses/start/<?php echo $data['Courses']['Course']['id']; ?>" class='right disable-hover'>
        <div class='button' id='start-course next-button' data-callbackdata="<?php echo $data['Courses']['Course']['name']; ?>" >Start Course</div>
    </a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

This is very strange, I am using the .ready function, so the html is available, because it can find the parent div. But when I try to find the child div, it can't find anything.

jQuery is loaded correctly, same as all the other stuff. It's all just static HTML. I am using CakePHP, but that should be not the problem.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Here is a problem `id='start-course next-button'` remove `next-button` from id

Comment: You shouldn't use spaces, the reason for this is simple, space character is not a valid for ID attribute.

Comment: HTML5 allows spaces and many more characters for IDs, though a space would need to be escaped in the selector. `$("start-course\\ next-button")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `id` is unique, you can only have one `id` for an element, so use:

```
id='start-course'
```

or:

```
id='next-button'
```

instead of:

```
id='start-course next-button'
```

Comment: Okay, that was indeed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @DijkeMark: if you have found the solution to your answer, then tick ANSWER to close this question.

Comment: I will within 8 minutes, I cant do it earlier

Answer (score 2):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

id='start-course next-button' is **NOT** OK. Try with **start-course_next-button**

If you want to find control by more than one "name" use classes

```
<div class="class1 class2"/>
```

**This should be OK**

```
   console.log($('.class1'));
   console.log($('.class2'));
   console.log($('.class1.class2'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple ids for same element -

```
id='start-course next-button'  // this is wrong
```

Although you can have multiple classed like this -

```
class='button start-course next-button' // you will need to replace # with .
```

Comment: Okay, that was indeed the problem. I always thought you could use multiple id's aslong as they were unique. I guess not when trying to retrieve the div by an id. Using multiple id's with css works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try "End with" selector

```
$("element[id$='txtTitle']")
```

ie

```
$("div[id$='next-button']")
```